# Vue прием данных с сервера

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vuex, state

Всем привет. 
Сразу хочу сказать,  что с vue знаком не так давно. 
Возникла у меня проблема.

Поучаю данные из сервера.

```
// store
import PostService from '../services/PostService'

export default {
  state: {
    posts: [],

  },
  actions: {
    async getPost() {
      const response = await PostService.fetchPosts();
      this.posts = response;
    }
  },
  mutations: {

  }
}
```

Тут масив для данных и запрос на сервер.
В `response` данные приходят.

```
// vue component 
<template>
    <section class="posts--wrap">
        <div class="posts wrapper">
            <h1>Posts</h1>
            <div
                    class="posts__item--wrap"
                    v-if="this.allPosts.length"
            >
                <h3>List of posts</h3>
                <div
                        v-for="(post, index) in allPosts"
                        :key="index"
                        class="posts__item">
                    <h3 class="posts__item-title">{{post.title}}</h3>
                    <p class="posts__item-text">{{post.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div
                    v-else
                    class="posts__item-error"
            >
                <h3>There are no posts ... Lets add one now!</h3>
                <router-link tag="div" :to="{name: 'Add'}">
                    <a>Add new post ;)</a>
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex';
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

    export default {
      name: 'PostPage',
      data () {
        return {

        }
      },
      computed: mapState({
        allPosts: state => state.posts.posts
      }),
      methods: {
        ...mapActions({
          getAllPosts: 'getPost'
        })
      },
      mounted() {
        console.log(this.allPosts);
        this.getAllPosts();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Если в `state.posts` что то добавить,  то на странице отобразится.

Но не могу вникунть как закинуть данные из `response`  в `posts`
Прошу помощи, или подсказки.
Спасибо!

Comment: покажите пожалуйста  код `PostService.fetchPosts()`

Comment: @AndreyPopov Я думаю,  что там все ок. Ибо в response данные попадают. Но вот ф-я  ```export default {  
  fetchPosts () {  
    return api().get('posts')  
  },  
  addNewPost (params) {  
    return api().post('posts', params)  
  }  
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во vuex изменение состояния `state` нужно делать через мутации, в вашем случае попробуйте сделать как я указал в примере:

```
export default {
  state: {
    posts: '',

  },
  actions: {
    async getPost({commit}) {
      const response = await PostService.fetchPosts();
      commit('SET_POST', response)
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_POST(state, payload) {
    state.post = payload
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Дополнительно почитаю доки.